# Google GeolocationAPI Requested entity was not found

Tags: javascript, google-geolocation

So Im trying to use the Google GeolocationAPI. It sends the quest successfully and also authenticates successfully with my api key but it returns me this

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 404,
            "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "notFound"
                }
            ],
            "status": "NOT_FOUND"
        }
    }
```

The url Im requesting to is https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_KEY with post as described in the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question? Did you read the docs to see what the errors are?

Comment: There is no specification about this error actually as far as I've seen it there is no specification for any error

Comment: Should tell you what the responses

Comment: I think I dont understand?

Comment: If you send an adrress or lat/long you get a response. If it can process that response it sends back location data, if it can't it sends back an error message like you receieved. That is documented

Comment: So you say Im not sending enough data for the api to give me results?

Comment: Not sure....you haven't shown you are sending anything other than api key

Comment: const googlePosition = await asyncFetch("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_KEY", 'POST'); thats what Im doing I thought that api would locate where I am

Comment: I am also having same issue. did you get it resolved?. can you tell me what was the issue exactly? @F4LS3

Comment: Does anyone have  a solution ?

Comment: I had a similar error, it helped just to wait and after a while it corrected itself. It is not clear why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to check out the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview):

As you can read:

> Before you start developing with the Geolocation API, review the
> authentication requirements (you need an API key) and the API usage
> and billing information (you need to enable billing on your project).

I was getting the exact same error until my billing information was validated. How I realized it, was using the geocoding API, which does return a better error.

Comment: In the documentation its says: "The request body must be formatted as JSON. The following fields are supported, and all fields are optional"

Comment: You are right @F4LS3
I updated the answer. I was having the exact same error and that did fix it.

Comment: My account is a verified billing account.But still I am facing the same issue. Can you please check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167163/unable-to-execute-rest-api-via-curl)?

Comment: @Moeez I answered your question but it was removed soon after that. I recommend you try making a request to Geocoding, because the errors in that API are more helpful than in Geolocation. I hope you can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create and associate a billing account to your project. It will work immediately.

Answer (score 0):

We started getting a 404 error just because our credit card expired and Google could not bill us. When we updated the billing information the API came to life again.

Answer (score 0):

usually, this error occurs when user access is revoked.